# Why doesn't Minitest run any tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I've used Minitest on several projects (both strictly Ruby and Rails) and haven't had much of an issue.  I just set up a Rails 4 project with Minitest and can't get the tests to run for some reason. This must be a stupid mistake on my part, but I can't see it.

The "error", "minitest running 0 tests", happens whether I use `rake` or `ruby Itest`.

I should also say that I know the test file is being recognized because if I take out the describe block, and just have `it should...`, I get a `NoMethodError` - `undefined method "it" for CalendarMakerTest:Class`.

```
#test

require 'test_helper'

class CalendarMakerTest < ActionView::TestCase

  describe "subject" do
    it "does something" do
      assert_equal false
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
#test_helper

require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/spec'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'


class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!

end
```

---

```
$ruby -Itest test/helpers/calendar_maker_test.rb

Run options: --seed 33758

# Running tests:



Finished tests in 0.035027s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Doesn't `assert_equal` need 2 arguments? I'd expect to see an `ArgumentError` exception if that was causing your problem, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the line

```
class CalendarMakerTest < ActionView::TestCase
```

Along with the corresponding `end` statement.  You will have better luck.

You are mixing up the ways to use Minitest with the spec and the autotest methodology.

You also don't technically need `require minitest/spec` when you require `minitest/autorun`.

Comment: that was it, cheers. do you know why that's causing such behavior (no errors, but no run tests)?

Comment: You create a class and then call describe and that is not the namespace it should be called in.